# how to remove transparency for a absolute position?

Tags: css

I have made a simple tooltip but the tooltip is transparent.
the background color is orange but I can see the below text from `tooltip1 dive`.
How can I remove transparency for `Tooltip1` dive?

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="First">xxxx</div>
<div style="position:absolute;background-color:#FFF799;width:100px;height:120px;border:solid 1px orange" id="Tooltip1"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
Sorry I supposed background is transparent.
I added z-index:1000 to `tooltip1` and problem solved.

Comment: Nothing in the CSS you show could create transparency. Is there other CSS in play?

Comment: Can you show a JSFiddle example or a screen shot?

Comment: Do you want to _introduce_ transparency or remove it? Your question is unclear. Please edit and rephrase it.

Comment: I want to remove the transparency

Comment: Thanks guys. I supposed background is transparent. I added z-index:1000 to `tooltip1` and my problem solved

Comment: His tooltip was showing up under the other div. Setting the z-index put it above it.